# Append number to list if string matches list name

Tags: python, string, list, match

I am trying to write a Python program as following:

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
list_c = []

listName  = str(input('insert list name: '))
listValue = int(input('insert value: '))
    listName.append(listValue)
```

But unfortunately "listName.append()" won't work.

Using only IF functions as in:

```
    if listName == 'list_a':
        list_a.append(listValue)
```

is impractical because I am actually working with 600+ lists...

Is there any other way I could do to make something like this work properly??

Help is much appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Is it practical to initialise 600+ lists firstly? You can have a dictionary with list of values.

Comment: Maybe initialising all those lists isn't practical indeed hehe. The thing is, I have 600+ names which I want to do some basic math with each one of those and I thought I would better define those 600+ names correctly at the beginning of the program.

After inputing every single number (let's take for example 5, 7 and -3), I am trying to achieve the following result:

`list_a = [5, 7, -3]

list_a result: 9`

Comment: Don't mix data and code unless you have to - looking up a variable by name and modifying it means the person using the script needs to know how it's coded. Then they may as well just import your code as module and write Python themselves. Please provide a description of what you're trying to achieve - what are you coding that needs these 600+ lists?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to build a simple calculator that computes total stock exchange purchases, total sales and final result for an individual investor. So, in my head it made sense using stock tickers (as in GOOG for Google Inc. stock, e.g.) as list names, and them adding purchases and sales to end up with something like this: `GOOG = [5, 7, -3]
total GOOG purchases: 12
total GOOG sales: 3
final result for GOOG: 9`
Do you guys have any suggestions?? I am all ears!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

When you're tempted to use variable names to hold data — like the names of stocks — you should almost certainly be using a dictionary with the data as keys. You can still pre-populate the dictionary if you want to (although you don't have to).

You can change your existing to code to something like:

```
# all the valid names
names = ['list_a', 'list_b', 'list_c']

# pre-populate a dictionary with them
names = {name:[] for name in names}

# later you can add data to the arrays:
listName  = str(input('insert list name: '))
listValue = int(input('insert value: '))
# append value
names[listName].append(listValue)
```

With this, all your data is in one structure. It will be easy to loop through it, make summary statistics like sums/averages act. Having a dictionary with 600 keys is no big deal, but having 600 individual variables is a recipe for a mess.

This will raise a key error if you try to add a name that doesn't exists, which you can catch in a try block if that's a possibility.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! Even though `eval(listName)` made my program work this far, I totally understand your point: I will be running in problems later... Sorry about not knowing the actual difference between lists and dictionaries. Will adapt my code to what you have suggest. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hope it helps @shingatame — also you should be very careful with `eval()`. It's almost never a good idea because it will run any code you give it, which has major security issues if you are using data from untrusted sources.

Comment: I guess `defaultdict(list)` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Yes, I would agree @Austin — trying not to add too much at once.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your lists in a dict. You could initialize your dict from a file, db, etc.

```py
lists = {"GOOG": []}

listName  = str(input('insert list name: '))
listValue = int(input('insert value: '))


lists.setdefault(listName,[]).append(listValue)

# Just a little output to see what you've got in there...
for list_name, list_value in lists.items():
    print(list_name, list_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, following Mark Meyer's and MSlimmer's suggestions above, I am using a dictionary of lists to simplify data input, which has made this section of my program work flawlessly (thanks again, guys!).

However, I am experiencing problems with the next section of my code (which was working before when I had it all as lists haha). I have a dictionary as below:

```
names = {'list_a':[5, 7, -3],  'list_b':[10, 12, -10, -10]}
```

Now, I have to add up all positives and all negatives to each list. I want it to have the following result:

```
names_positives = {'list_a': 12,  'list_b': 22}
names_negatives = {'list_a': -3,  'list_b': -20}
```

I have tried three different ways, but none of them worked:

```
## first try:
names_positives = sum(a  for a  in names.values() if a > 0)        

## second try:
names_positives = []
names_positives.append(a for a in names.values() if compras > 0)

## third try:
names_positives = dict(zip(names.keys(), [[sum(a)] for a in names.values() if compra > 0]))
```

To be honest, I have no idea how to proceed -- I am getting errors due to mixing strings and integers in those lines, and I am not being able to work some way around this problem... Any help is much appreciated. It could result in a dictionary, in a list or even in only the total sum (as in the first try, under no better circumstances).
Cheers!

Comment: You really should break this out into another question but... ```names_positives = {list_name: sum([list_positive for list_positive in list_value if list_positive > 0]) for list_name, list_value in names.items()}```

Comment: You were close but I think you forgot that .values() is a list of lists :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this one:

I just added one line for your code to work.

```
list_a = ['a']
list_b = []
list_c = []

listName  = str(input('insert list name: '))
listValue = int(input('insert value: '))

eval(listName).append(listValue)
```

the `eval` function evaluates the string into an actual python expression. It should be noted however that there are security issues regarding the use of eval. But for the exact question that you were trying to answer, this would be the easiest way that wouldn't require much refactoring of the existing code.

Comment: I added an element in `list_a` to check if it works. hopefully this is what you were looking for @shingatame

Comment: @shingatame, awesome! Can you accept my answer and put the checkmark then? or upvote it. thanks!

Comment: I would rather go with a solution that doesn't use `eval` even if I need to refactor the code a little bit.